# firewall-cmd in CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, firewall

I have a virtual linux server from STRATO. This machine runs CentOS 7 and when it comes to firewall settings I can read everywhere to use `firewall-cmd`. My system has no command available named like this and I can't find any instructions how to get it from any package in any repository. How can I get it? Where does it live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following command to find which package provides the file named 'firewall-cmd'.

# yum provides 'firewall-cmd'

The full path is not required. Partial file name is OK.
May be it will show that 'firewalld' package contains above file.
So you can install it with the following command.

# yum install firewalld

Cheers!